# AngularJS enter animation not playing on first run

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, ngroute

I'm having trouble running enter animation first time the page is loaded. I think this is an old problem having to do with this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5130).

You can see my problem [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g1PDFVrkaMmbcIHIzFQ4).

The strange thing is that when I put the templates in seperate files (and not as `text/ng-template`) the animation works flawlessly as you can see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Nuf7mmXTnA0q6hBgwUwW).

Since my application will work on file URI scheme I have to use `text/ng-template`.

Any workarounds? I couldn't find one that fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the dirty hack down [this page](http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5130#issuecomment-34371140).

Added `ng-if` to my `ng-view`'s container

```
<div ng-if="true" ng-view></div>
```

along with:

```
$rootElement.data("$$ngAnimateState").running = false;
```

in my first controller.

And here is the [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OUly4RK3TNuJMZR8tIa3).

Thank you.